# Select multiple rows in c# and pass data to a List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a `GridView` and  I would like to be able to select multiple rows and get the data from the column `mobilenumber` and add it to list of type string. How do  I that? This is what I tried but the code gives me error.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> selectedRows = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        string currentRow = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            currentRow += String.Format("{0} ", cell.FormattedValue);
        }
        selectedRows.Add(currentRow);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Count; i++)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(selectedRows[i]);
    }
}
```

aspx -

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" style="margin-left: 78px; margin-right: 0px">
    <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MobileNumber" HeaderText="MobileNumber" />
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @Roma - Error 6 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: GridView doesn't have a method/property called `SelectedRows`, the error message couldn't be much clearer.

Comment: Usually in ASP.NET you use a checkbox in each row to have a multiple rows selection. See https://www.codeproject.com/articles/831115/how-to-get-multiple-selected-rows-from-gridview-in

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows that there isn't a `SelectedRows` property on a GridView control. Looking at the [docs for GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx), the closest thing seems to be `SelectedRow` (singular). So it seems that the control doesn't normally allow you to select more than one row.

I found a tutorial which lets you [add a checkbox to each GridView row](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/831115/how-to-get-multiple-selected-rows-from-gridview-in) in order to select multiple, and this might help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of specific cell value by name.

Also `FormattedValue` returns an `object` and you are `adding object` to `List<string>` which will cause error so you need to call `.ToString()` method on `FormattedValue`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  string currentRow = string.Empty;
  currentRow += String.Format("{0} ", row.Cells["MobileNumber"].FormattedValue.ToString());
  selectedRows.Add(currentRow);
}
```